# getting class not found error in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working on laravel and following the tutorial `http://technetlk.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/laravel-backbonejs-coffeescript_3527.html`. currently working on 7th part of this tutorial.

in `routes.php` I have written

```
Route::any('api/category/(:num?)',
   array('as' => 'api.category',
        'uses' => 'api.category@index')
);
```

In `api/category.php`,

```
<?php
class Api_Category_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public $restful = true;
    public function get_index($id = null) 
    {
        if (is_null($id ))
        {
            $allCats = Category::all();
            return BaseModel::allToJson($allCats);
        }
        else
        {
            $cat = Category::find($id);
            return $cat->toJson();            
        }
    }
    public function post_index()
    {
            $cat = Input::json();
            $dbCat = new Category();
            $dbCat->code = $cat->code;
            $dbCat->name = $cat->name;
            $dbCat->save();
            return $dbCat->toJson();
    }

    public function put_index()
    {
            $cat = Input::json();
            $dbCat = Category::find($cat->id);
            $dbCat->code = $cat->code;
            $dbCat->name = $cat->name;
            $dbCat->save();
            return $dbCat->toJson();
    }
    public function delete_index($id = null)
    {
            $dbCat = Category::find($id);
            $dbCat->delete();        
    }    
}

?>
```

and in `BaseModel.php`

```
<?php
class Category extends BaseModel 
{
    public static $table = 'tbl_category';
}
class BaseModel extends Eloquent 
{
   public function toJson()
   {
     return json_encode($this->to_array());
   }
   public static function allToJson($array)
   {
      $temp = array();
      foreach($array as $t)
      {
          $temp[] = $t->to_array();                
      }
      return json_encode($temp);                    
    }
}
?>
```

when I am trying to run

```
curl -X POST http://lbc.dev/api/category -H "Content-Type: application/json" –d '{"code":"cat1", "name":"Category One"}'
```

I am getting the follwing error

> Unhandled Exception
>
> Message:
>
> Class 'Category' not found Location:
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\application\controllers\api\category.php on
>   line 9

Answer (score 1):

Your Category Model should be located in /application/models/category.php

Your BaseModel class should be located in /application/models/basemodel.php

The following is if your BaseModel class is not in a defined Autoloader directory:

> Another problem you may face is the BaseModel not autoloading
>   correctly. This can be fixed by appending this line of code to your
>   start.php file found in your application folder:
>
> ```
> // Autoloader::map
> 'BaseModel' => path('app').'/path/to/basemodel.php',
> ```

Comment: thanx Joel, but I am not getting what this path of basemodel is `path('app').'/path/to/basemodel.php'`

Comment: You probably won't need to map to the `BaseModel`, but make sure that both are within `application/models`.

Comment: Jason Lewis is right. The Autoloader::map code is only needed if you don't save your BaseModel class to "application/models/basemodel.php".

Answer (score 1):

U have to **specify the model in controller file** before using it

Add this line above  the following line in your controller file

**use App\Category;**

class Api_Category_Controller extends Base_Controller
{